# Looking to have Raspberry Pi Zero act as USB mouse

Tags: usb, otg

I’m looking to use a Raspberry Pi Zero to act as a USB mouse for a computer. I’m wanting to move my mouse on a remote computer and have it correspond and move the cursor on the PC the PiZero is connected to. In other words, I want to do a Remote Desktop except control it via USB instead of software on the host computer. Is this possible or is there a better way?
[image]

Additionally my objective is to control the computer remotely without there being any indication that the input is anything other than a standard USB mouse.

Comment: Raspberry Pi Zero (or any HDMI output) can't be changed to be an input. You need a HDMI->USB grabber/converter, so you need just one Raspberry Pi. Take a look at https://pikvm.org/ as it's goal is just what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is an OpenSource Project called PiKVM. You can not only remotely use your mouse, but also keyboard an see your monitor output. It works with a Raspberry PI Zero W, but has a lot more performance with a Raspberry PI 4.

Link https://pikvm.org/